# Validate Second Name using regex if the string contains hyphen

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem with validating second name using regex in Java.

I use [Pattern.compile](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String)) method to compile the given regular expression into a pattern. And [Pattern.mathcer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher(java.lang.CharSequence)) method to create a matcher that will match the given input against this pattern.

I need to validate second name if string contains hyphen.

This is my function to validate:

```
/**
     *   Determines if the string is valid and returns result code
     *
     *   @param fio                  string to validate
     *   @return                     1 - valid second name, name, patronymic; 2 - valid second name, name; 0 - invalid string
     */
    public static int Validate(String fio) {
        Pattern pattern;
        Matcher matcher;
        try {
            pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z])[a-z]+ ([A-Z])[a-z]+ ([A-Z])[a-z]+"); //second name; name; patronymic
            matcher = pattern.matcher(fio);
            if (matcher.matches()) return 1;

            pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z])[a-z]+ ([A-Z])[a-z]+"); //second name; name
            matcher = pattern.matcher(fio);
            if (matcher.matches()) return 2;

        } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex1) {
            System.out.println("String is incorrect!");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Could you tell me how to change my regex string pattern to validate second name with hyphen?

Comment: `fio` is for `Фамилия Имя Отчество`? :) Don't you want `\p{L}` to match Unicode letters?

Comment: Of course I use such abbreviation :)

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you want to do. Match an optional `-` in one of the names? Like `\p{L}+(?:-\p{L}+)?`?

Comment: I am new in regex. I think so. I just need to determine if second name string contains hyphen using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
public static int Validate(String fio) {
    //second name; name; patronymic
    if (fio.matches("\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+(?:-\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+)* \\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+ \\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+")) {
        return 1;
    }
    //second name; name
    if (fio.matches("\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+(?:-\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+)* \\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+")) {
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+(?:-\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)*` regex matches

- `\p{Lu}` - an uppercase Unicode letter
- `\p{Ll}+` - 1+ lowercase Unicode letters
- `(?:-\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\p{Lu}` - an uppercase Unicode letter
  - `\p{Ll}+` - 1+ lowercase Unicode letters

See a [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/7V7VD1):

```java
System.out.println(Validate("Стриженов Анатолий Иванович"));
// => 1
System.out.println(Validate("Стриженов Анатолий"));
// => 2
System.out.println(Validate("Стриженов-Бродский Анатолий Иванович"));
// => 1
System.out.println(Validate("Стриженов-Бродский Анатолий"));
// => 2
System.out.println(Validate("Стриженов"));
// => 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but what is wrong with my regex string? Is it possible to add hyphen checking to it?

Comment: @WideWood I added it. `(?:-[A-Z][a-z]+)*` is the ASCII equivalent of my suggestion above.